# How can I get certain types of files dropped in certain folders based on file type?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I was wondering if it is possible to have the following:

In my *Downloads* folder, I have 2 subfolders : *IMAGES* and *VIDEOS*. Is it possible to automatically move every image downloaded to the *Downloads* folder to the *IMAGES* folder, and if VIDEO files are downloaded in the *Downloads* folder, it should go into the *VIDEOS* subfolder?

I thought I could do it with Smart Folders but it does not seems to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create two folder actions, one for images:

[image]

one for videos:

[image]

Both should be setup to receive files from Downloads folder.

The first step filters images and videos files.

The second step moves those files in the appropriate folder.

Be sure that folder action is attached to your `Downloads` directory (right click on directory, `Services\Folder Actions Setup...`).

To let Automator wait for the download to complete, you can add a `Run AppleScript` step, before the `Move Finder Items` step, similar to this:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    if input is {} then
        return {}
    end if

    repeat
        delay 1
        set {size:fileSize, busy status:Busy} to (info for (input as alias))
        if not Busy and (fileSize is greater than 0) then return input
    end repeat
end run
```

[image]

Comment: The thing is that during the file download, it moves the temporary download file to the folder, so once the download is over, it makes an error. Is there anything to make it wait until the download is over?

Comment: I updated the answer with something that should work.

Comment: It does not work. It downloads the file in the DOWNLOAD folder, but nothing happens after that. The file is not moving to the MUSIC folder

Comment: This is strange. The added script waits for the file to be released, then it passes it to the `Move Finder Items` step. I tested it on Mac OSX Lion. What version have you?

Comment: I have Mac OSX Lion too. Can you make a screen shot of all the window once the automator file is all set please? Maybe I'm doing something wrong...Thanks a lot

Comment: Screenshot added!

Comment: I'm still getting an error : Something about the "alias" thing in the script. "Impossible to render {} in alias type" (my computer is in french so I translated it...)

Comment: Try to remove `as alias` from the code, and let me know.

Comment: Not working either...It now says "Can't find file" at the Apple Script step

Comment: I think I now understand the problem. This happens when the filter action has an empty output (for example you downloaded a video and the filter keeps only images). I added an if to the script: this way there should never be errors.

Answer (score 0):

Fill in the movieFiles property with the name extensions of the movies you will be dropping. Save the script in your folder actions folder and attach the folder action to your target folder

```
property movieFiles : {"mov", "m4v"}

on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theFiles
    repeat with aFile in theFiles
        tell application "System Events"
            if name extension of aFile is in movieFiles then
                move aFile to (theFolder & "VIDEOS" as text)
            else
                move aFile to (theFolder & "IMAGES" as text)
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```